# POST Request to Azure DevOps Backlogs

Tags: reactjs, post, azure-devops, backlog

Hey I was just wondering can you write code in a React application that sends a POST request to the Azure API but specifically create a backlog? I can see you can perform a GET request but haven't seen anything about POST

I have been on their documentation and it covers GET but I do not see anything about POST

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, you cannot create any backlog instances at all. Since there is no support in doing this via the WebGUI, I would assume that there is also no REST-API call for it.

From a logical (or agile) point of view, having backlog instances makes no sense as well: Either a work item (task / user story /... you name it) is part of a sprint or it is placed in the backlog.

This is also the way DevOps handles your work items: If you create a new work item it is placed in the backlog (single instance) by default. When adding it to a sprint, it will be moved out of the backlog.

**TL;DR: I guess it is not possible on intention.**

Answer (score 0):

after checking in azure devops, if you are about create a backlog page in boards for workitems, then you could not separately create a single backlog page.

You need to create a new team and the backlog for the team will be generated automatically.

You could refer to this doc for [team creation rest api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/teams/create?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP).

My api is below.

```
post https://dev.azure.com/<orgname>/_apis/projects/<projectID>/teams?api-version=5.1-preview.3
```

request body

```
{
 "description":"",
 "projectId":"<projectID>",
 "name":"<teamname>",
 "identity":
           {
            "customDisplayName":"<teamname>"
           }
}
```